# How to find searched text in wijmo grid angular2

Tags: angular, angular-components, wijmo-grid

I am trying to search text in wijmo grid using angular2. What i have to do is on button click i have to pass text and searching text and i have to highlight the text.I am new to angular 2 and wijmo grid.can anyone please help me how to achieve in angular2.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try by loop itemsSource and search text on it.